# How do I download a dynamically-created file in a form submission?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've got a form that builds an array of data. On submission, it updates a table displayed in the browser, using AJAX; that works fine.

I want a second submit button that downloads the same data as a CSV file. I've tried a number of variations, but I can't seem to both send the file response and satisfy the AJAX requirement for a returned array.

The button:

```
$form['download'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Download data'),
  '#weight' => '40',
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::downloadCallback',
    'event' => 'click',
  ],
];
```

...and the response section of the callback:

```
$file_content = $serializer->serialize($data, 'csv');
$response = new Response($file_content);
$disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'data.csv');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

I've also tried using this instead of setResponse:

```
$response->send();
```

These all result in an error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer::renderResponse() must be of the type array, null given, called in /mnt/www/html/mowebd8dev/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php on line 89 in /mnt/www/html/mowebd8dev/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/AjaxRenderer.php on line 45 #0 /mnt/www/html/mowebd8dev/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php(89): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer->renderResponse(NULL, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))

I've tried also returning a simple render array with some dummy markup, and that prevents the error, but still doesn't result in a file download. Is there a way to accomplish this? Or should I just not be using AJAX for this purpose?

Comment: You can't download a file with AJAX directly (for security reasons). In my experience the way to solve it is to redirect to a URL that sets the content disposition header, which has the same effect because browsers don't change the URL when encountering such a response. So one approach would be to save the file instead of serving it directly, with a hashed filename, then return a `RedirectCommand` from the AJAX callback with the URL for a route you create that takes that hash as a parameter. In the controller, load up the tmp file that matches the hash, serve it, then delete it. Voila

Comment: A cron job to clear up orphaned files after a period of time would also be wise if you go with that approach.

Comment: I believe I was overthinking it. By creating a response and setting the form response to it, I get the desired effect without ajax -- the file downloads, but the form doesn't reload and the output region isn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

I was off-track in even trying to do this with AJAX, as Clive mentioned in his comment. Instead, I just made it a normal submit button, and then overrode the form action. The result is that the data is downloaded as a file, the form doesn't reload, and the data output section doesn't update, which is the desired behavior in this case.

The button, along with a new format element:

```
$form['download']['format'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $this->getValidFormats(),
  '#title' => $this->t('Select format'),
  '#weight' => '0',
];
$form['download']['download'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Download'),
  '#weight' => '10',
];
```

The submit function:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  switch ($form_state->getValue('op')->__toString()) {
    case 'Download':
      $this->download($form, $form_state);
      break;
  }
}
```

And the relevant part of the download function:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

$response = new Response($file_content);
$disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'data.' . $format);
$response->headers->set('Content-type', $content_types[$format]);
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
$response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', strlen($file_content));
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```